# Vertical Align Crystal Report Text Filed

Tags: crystal-reports, formatting, formula

I have a scenario in which my reports fields doesn't look like centered Vertically,

Below is the screen Short of the output.
[image]

As it can bee seen from output that data with a bigger font is clearly seen centered vertically, but the data pointed with lines is `left-top` justified, i want that to be `left-centered`.
For vertical alignment I did this .
[image]
and code behind formula is:

```
if {NewReport;1.TireLevel} = 1 
then 
   crCenteredHorizontally
else
   crLeftAligned
```

The Editor Screen.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, Crystal Reports doesn't support vertical alignment in the same way it supports horizontal.

It's possible to use labels on the vertical ruler and enforce Snap to Grid, but that might not work within a table. Or you can add line breaks, blank rows, or plain white objects to push things into position. But there's no easy way to enforce a vertical center.

---

In your particular case, I would actually make two seperate fields: One for large text and one for small text. Layer them on top of each other and reuse your current formula to alternate their suppression. This way you can move the smaller text vertically down without undoing the vertical alignment on the large text field.

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering there may be some padding effect we can add to achieve this on selected conditions

Comment: Can you submit a screenshot of your design screen for the table? I can help you decide which method of cheating them out is best for you.

Comment: If you can see the output the field is same for Larger Fonts and medium, it dynamically make font bigger upon a condition.

Comment: It's a bit of a hack, but you could make two separate fields, one for Larger and one for Medium. Put them on top of each other, suppress them based on the same condition you use to make the font bigger.

Comment: :) great idea.. indeed. I will do it this way.

Comment: Cool. I'll edit this answer to reflect that idea. We kind of went overboard on the comments haha

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120650/discussion-between-daredevil-and-4444).